# How to get public ipv4 instead of ipv6

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, ip

I recently upgraded my broadband connection so the new one has both ipv6 and ipv4. My previous one had ipv4 only. I want to put ipv4 in a variable in a batch file instead of ipv6. The current commands which i use gives the default ip so earlier it used to store ipv4 in the variable but now it's storing ipv6 in it. I have no idea how to get ipv4 because the nslookup I'm using only gives ipv6.
Here is my current batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions Disabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%~dp0"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%A in (
  'nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>NUL^|find "Address:"'
) Do set ExtIP=%%B

<save.ip set /p SavIP=
if "%SavIP%" neq "%ExtIP%" (
  echo %date% %time~0,5% : IP changed from %SavIP% to %ExtIP%.
  >save.ip echo %ExtIP%
  start http://%ExtIP%             #this is where I put the url
) else (
  echo ExtIP didn't change. Nothing to do.
)
```

Comment: You probably need to clear or disable the DNS cache in your router, and refresh. Either way these aren't issues with your command, or script, they're issues with your hardware/software configuration settings.

Comment: is it because I'm using the dns server provided by my isp? let me check with 1.1.1.1

Comment: What is output on running in a console window `nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com`? Are there not two lines output with `Addresses:` containing the IPv6 address and below is the IPv4 address of the domain looked up? It looks like you filter on the wrong line of the output. The line starting with `Address:` has the IP address of the gateway.

Comment: What is the output of the command `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Resolve-DnsName -Name 'myip.opendns.com' -Server 'resolver1.opendns.com'"`?

Comment: Mofi no it just has ipv6

Comment: lit it gives nothing

Comment: How about the command `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Resolve-DnsName -Name 'myip.opendns.com' -Server 'resolver1.opendns.com'"`?

Comment: It gives nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this batch file and it works on my side 5/5 !

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Public IP by Powershell and Batch
@for /f "delims=" %%# in (
'PowerShell -C "Resolve-DnsName -Name "'myip.opendns.com'" -Server "'resolver1.opendns.com'" | select IPAddress" ^| findstr "\."'
) do Set "MyPublicIP=%%#"
echo My Public IP Address  = %MyPublicIP%
pause
```

---

And here is another one that call a subroutine `:GetPublic_IP <Target> <IP>`

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Public IP by Powershell and Batch
Set "MyPublicIP=myip.opendns.com"
Set "Google=www.google.com"
Set "Yahoo=www.yahoo.com"
Set "Stack=www.stackoverflow.com"

Call :GetPublic_IP "%MyPublicIP%" MyPublicIP 
echo My Public IP Address       = %MyPublicIP%
Call :GetPublic_IP "%Google%" Google_IP 
echo Google IP Address          = %Google_IP%
Call :GetPublic_IP "%Yahoo%" Yahoo_IP 
echo Yahoo IP Address           = %Yahoo_IP%
Call :GetPublic_IP "%Stack%" Stack_IP
echo Stackoverflow IP Address   = %Stack_IP%
pause
EXIT
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetPublic_IP <Target> <IP>
@for /f "delims=" %%# in (
'PowerShell -C "Resolve-DnsName -Name '"%~1"' -Server "'resolver1.opendns.com'" | select IPAddress" ^| findstr "\."'
) do Set "%2=%%#
Exit /B
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this issue in default gateway rather than the given code.
Prior to my changes, the command worked fine and returned my public IPv4 address that I've used to host servers of my own.

I did the following:

1. 192.168.1.1 --> or whatever your default gateway is
2. Logged in using "admin" and "password" --> or if you've changed them whatever works
3. Navigated to **Advanced** > **Advanced Setup** > **IPv6**
4. Changed the setting from **Disabled** to **DHCP**

Toggling these two settings results in either IPv6 getting returned or IPv4 getting returned. When you toggle, you may need to re-open cmd, but since your using a .bat you can probably just rerun it.

Keep in mind I'm using Spectrum and your default gateway settings may be labeled differently. And you can always re-toggle IPv6 if you desire to use it for a later project.